# UDP Client Segmentation Error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, client-server

**Please help! This is due in a few hours and I've had no luck w/ online searches**

CODE:

/*
Description:
The client should first send a datagram to the LocationServer.
The LocationServer will be listening on port number 23510 of the host c-lnx001.engr.uiowa.edu.
The message contained in this datagram should be the specified UserID (no null characters, blanks, line-feeds, or other extraneous characters).
The LocationServer will respond with a datagram containing the following information:
[WeatherServer hostname]  [WeatherServer port #]
*/

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>  /* for fprintf */
#include <string.h> /* for memcpy */
#include <strings.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 2048
```

int main(){

```
struct hostent *hp;     /* host information */
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;    /* server address */
char *my_message = "laura\0";/*USERID as message to server*/
char *buf_addr;
char *host = "c-lnx001.engr.uiowa.edu\0";
int port = 23510;
int fd;

/* fill in the server's address and data */
//memset((char*)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); ?
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(23510);

/* look up the address of the server given its name */
hp = gethostbyname("c-lnx001.engr.uiowa.edu");
if (!hp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not obtain address of %s\n", host);
    return 0;
}



/* put the host's address into the server address structure */
// DOESN't WORK: memcpy((void *)&servaddr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length);

bcopy(hp->h_addr,(char*)&servaddr.sin_addr,hp->h_length);

if((fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM, 0))<0)
{
    exit(2);

}

/* send a message to the server */
if (sendto(fd, my_message, strlen(my_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) 
{
    perror("sendto failed");
    return 0;
}
int addrlen = sizeof(servaddr);

recvfrom(fd,buf_addr,SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,&addrlen);
printf("%s\n", buf_addr);
```

}

Comment: char *buf_addr is uninitialized when used in the recvfrom() call.

Comment: Look very carefully at ALL C 'string' calls in network code.  C does not have strings, it has arays of chars that must be nul terminated.

Comment: Oh - missed the 'urgent' plea in bold - have a downvote.

Comment: Also, googling 'C UDP client' reveals: 'About 4,670,000 results', the first of which is a reasonable example.  Note that the recvfrom is followed by the addition of a  terminating null.  'I've had no luck w/ online searches' - yeah, right.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're not resetting the serveraddr
Here's a working copy

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define IP_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT 5060

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int recBytes, clientSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    char buf[80], msg[]="greeting to server";
    const int msgLen = sizeof(msg);
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t reSize;

    memset(&serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), 0);

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    inet_aton(IP_ADDRESS, &serverAddr.sin_addr);

    if(sendto(clientSocket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) != (sizeof(msg)))
    {
        perror("sendto");
        return -1;
    }

    reSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    if((recBytes = recvfrom(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, &reSize)) == -1)
    {
        perror("recvfrom");
        return -1;
    }
    buf[recBytes]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: printf in network code is misused nearly as much as strlen().  The protocol described by the OP does not define a terminating null and the automatic storage char buf[80] is not initialized to nulls and the 'recbytes' returned by the recvfrom() call is not used to add a terminating null.  It's possible that buf may not hold an added null anyway if a datagram of 80 bytes has been received.